# Parallel multiprocessing with Pool class much slower than single thread approach

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I am writing a code that requires heavy calculations at specific parts of the program. The main bottleneck of the code occurs during a `for` loop for which terms are independent, but need to share some common data to perform the calculations.

I thought that when arriving at this point of the program, `Pool` class would allow for efficient parallelization of this loop. However, when I run it in serial, it seems to be much faster than when using the `Pool` class, and I am struggling to see why. Here is a piece of the code that implements the parallelization:

```
def function( some_keys_list, args ):
    result  = [] 
    number_processors      = mp.cpu_count()
    number_used_processors = number_processors # yes, I am using all


    total_items            = len( some_keys_list )  

    a_keys = args[4]
    b_keys = args[5]
    c_keys = args[6]   

    ids_list = ["a"]*len( a_keys  ) + ["b"]*len( b_keys  ) + ["c"]*len( c_keys  )


    #try pool map method            
    from functools import partial

    func = partial( pool_worker_function, args )
    pool = mp.Pool( processes = number_used_processors )

    iter_t = list( zip( some_keys_list, ids_list ) )               
    pool.map_async( func, iter_t, callback = result.append )
    pool.join()
    pool.close()
```

The arguments `args` passed to the worked function is a tuple `( args[0], args[1],...)`, containing different data structures, for instance, arrays of size NxM, i.e., `a[0] = array(N,M)` and so on. Could it be that because of the huge size of these data structures, the parallelization is actually slower than the single threaded approach? I just want to know what is going wrong here and I wouldn't have expected this behaviour in first place.

**Edit:** For completeness, here is what the tuple passed as argument to the worker looks like:

`args = (  a_1, a_2, ...., a_N)` where all the arguments represent **different** data structures.

Comment: `multiprocessing` will pickle arguments and results to pass between processes and yeah, that can be more expensive than the savings from parallelizing the routine. If you are on a forking system like linux, you can put your data in a global variable, say a list, and only pass down the index to the list. Assuming you created the pool after creating the list, the child will have a view of that list. Doesn't work for windows, though. And I think partial functions are problematic here because they have to wrap part of the data you want to use.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply! I am actually using Windows OS on my own machine, so all debugging part when writing my code is being done on Windows... but it is meant to be running on a linux OS machine once is finished, so I don't know how this could be made easier... Any suggestions in general?

Comment: You could setup a linux VM on windows to more closely match your target environment.

Comment: Depending on the work your code is doing, numpy and pandas release the GIL for block operations and can be usefully multithreaded in the same process.

Comment: Thanks all for the useful comments, I can see now the remedy can be a bit worse than the disease in this specific case; probably the best option is to reconfigure the code in numpy and forget about multi--processing.

Comment: And just to note, its the bulk operations on arrays that parallelize. Yes: `np.array(list(range(1000))).sum()`, No: `sum(np.array(list(range(1000)))`, etc...